# Is it against the definition of polygon for edges or vertices to overlap or being the same point or segment

Tags: geometry, polygons, plane-geometry

I think question shows what I'm after but I will try to add some more details. So there are two cases:

1. I have a polygon `ABCDEC'(A)`. `C'` is a different point to `C`, but on a plane has exactly the same coordinates as `C`.
2. I have a polygon `ABCDEC(A)`. `C` is a point on a plane which is used in the same polygon twice.

I couldn't find a definition which would prove those two to be incorrect. So my assumption is that they're perfectly valid polygons. Is it correct?

Comment: As [looking at this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) will show, there are a fair number of inequivalent definitions of polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture from Wikipedia showing some polygons. Note that three of them self intersect at a point (more than once for the regular star). Now, this diagram is not rigid at all when it comes to naming polygons, but I would say most definitions would agree that they are all polygons.... it is entirely dependent on your definition though. It is assumed that if you construct a polygon as you do in your post that you allow for this to occur. It is more a case by case basis... in some cases it is useful to break up an intersecting polygon into multiple non-intersecting polygons, and in some cases it is better to leave the polygon as one unit.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, agreed that for some calculations or rendering purposes it would be useful to break it down into simpler non-intersecting polygons. It's more of a theoretical question at this stage, and your answer makes a lot of sense, confirming what I thought about it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try drawing out the points and the shapes themselves. If you draw out polygon 2 (i.e. draw points A-E and connect them as indicated), you'll see that this actually gives two shapes. So it's not necessarily *against* the definition of a polygon, but it does NOT produce a *single* polygon.

Comment: How would you define a shape though?

Comment: In Euclid's Elements book 1, Euclid says that a shape is defined by its boundary lines. So with the above polygons, you are actually creating two shapes, rather than one.